# stopwatch and timer, problems with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, timer, stopwatch

I'm new with dart and flutter and currently I'm studying so please don't judge me for this (maybe) symple question.
I am trying to build a timer but all my code started from a stopwatch so I guess that's the first problem.
In few words, I'm trying to create a timer from 3 minutes that I can stop and start anytime I want (it suppose to be a referee tool) but my starting string is '03:00' and I can see that, so that's fine, I can't find any answer though on how the time can run from 03:00 minutes to 00:00.
Also, as you can see in my code I created a button to reset the time but it always goes back to 00:00 and not to 03:00.
Anyone who can help? I'm definitely missing something.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewStopWatch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewStopWatchState createState() => _NewStopWatchState();
}

class _NewStopWatchState extends State<NewStopWatch> {
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch();
  Timer timer;
  bool startStop = true;

  IconData btnPlayStatus = Icons.play_arrow;

  String elapsedTime = '03:00';

  updateTime(Timer timer) {
    if (watch.isRunning) {
      setState(() {
        elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(watch.elapsedMilliseconds);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(elapsedTime, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60.0)),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                    shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(),
                    heroTag: "btn1",
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () => startOrStop(),
                    child: Icon(btnPlayStatus)),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 50,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(),
                    heroTag: "btn2",
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () => resetWatch(), //resetWatch,
                    child: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_left)),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  resetWatch() {
    setState(() {
      watch.reset();
      setTime();
    });
  }

  startOrStop() {
    if(startStop) {
      setState(() {
        btnPlayStatus = Icons.pause;
      });
      startWatch();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        btnPlayStatus = Icons.play_arrow;
      });
      stopWatch();
    }
  }

  startWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = false;
      watch.start();
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), updateTime);
    });
  }

  stopWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = true;
      watch.stop();
      setTime();
    });
  }

  setTime() {
    var timeSoFar = watch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    setState(() {
      elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(timeSoFar);
    });
  }

  transformMilliSeconds(int milliseconds) {
    int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();

    String minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    return "$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to think if you always want to start from 3 minutes; if so create a static field as follows:

```
static duration = new Duration(minutes:3);
```

Edit: I've refactored your code and made it working.

```
updateTimer(Timer t) {
    if (watch.isRunning) {
      setState(() {
        Duration newDuration = _NewStopWatchState.duration -
            new Duration(milliseconds: watch.elapsedMilliseconds);
        elapsedTime = durationToMinutesAndSeconds(newDuration);
      });
    }
}
```

This is the updateTimer function.
Next, you didn't update your stopWatch() function to take care of the new changes so I changed it for you.

```
stopWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = true;
      watch.stop();
      Duration newDuration = _NewStopWatchState.duration -
          new Duration(milliseconds: watch.elapsedMilliseconds);
      elapsedTime = durationToMinutesAndSeconds(newDuration);
    });
}
```

I've also updated the resetWatch() function

```
resetWatch() {
    setState(() {
      watch.reset();
      elapsedTime = durationToMinutesAndSeconds(_NewStopWatchState.duration);
    });
}
```

I've also created an utility function to convert a duration to minutes and seconds.

```
String durationToMinutesAndSeconds(Duration d) {
    return "${d.inMinutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}" +
            ":${d.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
}
```

I've tried it on my machine and the code is working, hope this time is working even on your side.

Comment: So, in few words now I modified the code as you suggested but there are few things that are not working:
- the 3 minutes appears as elapsedTime and is static when I click play button,
- When I play pause button it shows the seconds that are actually passed,
- when I click on reset button it gives me "3:0" instead of "03:00".

I post below all my code so you can review it

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but you changed the implementation of startWatch: when you're initializing the timer you're not referencing the updateTimer function anymore, you're calling it with (). As for the wrong padding of the string you can use toString().padLeft(2,'0') for minutes and seconds. Try to make these changes. It should be working as expected now

Comment: Hi Marco, 
it might be easier than it looks to me but I don't understand.
I'm a total beginner and this project it's probably something that isn't quite my level yet but using flutter to develop something for my work place it's challenging so I like it.
I don't understand how things work with this timer, I applied the changes you suggested but still it's not working. 
I don't understand where is the mistake

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you a completed view of what you need to write to make the StopWatch working

Answer (score 0):

That's the modified code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewStopWatch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewStopWatchState createState() => _NewStopWatchState();
}

class _NewStopWatchState extends State<NewStopWatch> {
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch();
  Timer timer;
  bool startStop = true;
  static Duration duration = Duration(minutes:3);

  IconData btnPlayStatus = Icons.play_arrow;

  String elapsedTime = '';

  updateTimer() {
    if (watch.isRunning) {
      setState(() {
        elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(_NewStopWatchState.duration.inMilliseconds - watch.elapsedMilliseconds);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(elapsedTime),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                    shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(),
                    heroTag: "btn1",
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () => startOrStop(),
                    child: Icon(btnPlayStatus)),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 50,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(),
                    heroTag: "btn2",
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () => resetWatch(), //resetWatch,
                    child: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_left)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  resetWatch() {
    setState(() {
      watch.reset();
      setTime();
      elapsedTime="${_NewStopWatchState.duration
          .inMinutes}:${_NewStopWatchState.duration.inSeconds.remainder(60)}";
    });
  }

  startOrStop() {
    if(startStop) {
      setState(() {
        btnPlayStatus = Icons.pause;
      });
      startWatch();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        btnPlayStatus = Icons.play_arrow;
      });
      stopWatch();
    }
  }

  startWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = false;
      watch.start();
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), updateTimer());
    });
  }

  stopWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = true;
      watch.stop();
      setTime();
    });
  }

  setTime() {
    var timeSoFar = watch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    setState(() {
      elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(timeSoFar);
    });
  }

  transformMilliSeconds(int milliseconds) {
    int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();

    String minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    return "$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a stop watch also with timer you can use my easy github project.
I hope this will will help some one. Thank you.[image]

[Here you can get my github repo](https://github.com/anandh-ps/timer)